# SpringBoot.run error, I don't know why the error occurred

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle

Problem when running spring boot tomcat server.
I also tried Invalidate Cahces/Restart but same thing.

```java
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class TestSpringBootApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringBootApplication.run(TestSpringBootApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Here, an error occurs at this part of `.run`.

`Cannot resolve method 'run' in 'SpringBootApplication'.`

`cannot find symbol method run(class<TestSpringBootApplication>, String[])`

build.gradle

```java
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.5.3'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id "com.ewerk.gradle.plugins.querydsl" version "1.0.10"
    id 'java'
}
```

Comment: `SpringBootApplication` is the annotation, use `SpringApplication.run` to run it.

Comment: @M. Deinum Thanks for your help.